# Конвертация смещённой изометрической карты в 2Д массив

Tags: python, массивы, 2d, преобразование, поиск-пути

У меня есть изометрическая шахматная карта, на которой я хочу реализовать перемещение юнитов.

[my map](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iJxi6.jpg)

У меня готова карта перемещений, которая генерирует возможные ходы на 8 направлений, но она работает с 2D-массивом.

**Мне нужно перевести смещённую изометрическую карту в 2-D пространство для дальнейших преобразований**.

Нужна помощь либо с преобразованием и взаимодействием с моей функцией поиска пути, либо любые другие варианты.

Вот графический пример расположения карты и массива: у меня не алмазная карта, а смещённая.

[img1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PcvSr.jpg) [img2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NcvJh.jpg)

Результат выполнения:

[-1.0, -1.0, -1.0, -1.0, -1.0, -1.0, -1.0, -1.0, -1.0, -1.0]

[-1.0, -1.0, -1.0, -1.0, -1.0, -1.0, -1.0, -1.0, -1.0, -1.0]

[-1.0, -1.0, -1.0, -1.0, -1.0, 0.0, -1.0, -1.0, -1.0, -1.0]

[-1.0, -1.0, -1.0, 0.0, 0.5, 1.0, 0.5, 0.0, -1.0, -1.0]

[-1.0, -1.0, -1.0, 0.5, 1.5, 2.0, 1.5, 0.5, -1.0, -1.0]

[-1.0, -1.0, 0.0, 1.0, 2.0, 3.0, 2.0, 1.0, 0.0, -1.0]

[-1.0, -1.0, -1.0, 0.5, 1.5, 2.0, 1.5, 0.5, -1.0, -1.0]

[-1.0, -1.0, -1.0, 0.0, 0.5, 1.0, 0.5, 0.0, -1.0, -1.0]

[-1.0, -1.0, -1.0, -1.0, -1.0, 0.0, -1.0, -1.0, -1.0, -1.0]

[-1.0, -1.0, -1.0, -1.0, -1.0, -1.0, -1.0, -1.0, -1.0, -1.0]

Код программы:

```
h = 10
w = 10
rm = [[-1.00 for k in range(w)] for g in range(h)]


def generate_move_map(x, y, moves=3):

    if rm[x][y] < float(moves):
        rm[x][y] = float(moves)
        for _x in range(-1, 2):  # Проходит циклом вокруг центра
            for _y in range(-1, 2):
                if (_x, _y) != (0, 0):
                    nX = _x + x
                    nY = _y + y
                    if 0 <= nX < w and 0 <= nY < h:  # w = 10, h = 10
                        if abs(_x) + abs(_y) == 2:
                            move_weight = 1.5
                        else:
                            move_weight = 1
                        t = moves - move_weight * pm[nX][nY]
                        if t >= 0:
                            generate_move_map(nX, nY, t)
                _y += 1
            _x += 1


generate_move_map(5, 5)

for f in rm:
    print(f)
```

Comment: Правильно ли я понимаю, что вы, грубо говоря, хотите, зная координаты клика по смещенной карте, найти "обычные" координаты клетки, по которой кликнули, и наооборот?

Comment: да, нужно было найти обычные координаты

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Нашёл такой способ поиска возможных путей к нужной точке:

```
from collections import deque

import config  # Мой файл с настройками


def screenToLinear(scrx, scry):
    linx = scrx - scry // 2
    liny = -scrx - (scry + 1) // 2
    return linx, liny


def linearToScreen(linx, liny):
    rotx = (linx - liny) // 2
    roty = (-linx - liny)
    return rotx, roty


class PathNode:
    def __init__(self):
        self.value = 0
        self.prev = None
        self.cost = None

    def __str__(self):
        return '{:3}'.format(self.value)


fwidth = 25
fheight = 50

pathField = [[PathNode() for _ in range(fheight)] for _ in range(fwidth)]


def inField(x, y):
    return 0 <= x < fwidth and 0 <= y < fheight


def clearPathField():
    for x in range(fwidth):
        for y in range(fheight):
            pathField[x][y].value = 0
            pathField[x][y].prev = None


sideStepCost = 10
cornerStepCost = 15


def sidesOf(x, y):
    if y % 2 == 0:
        return [(x - 1, y - 1), (x - 1, y + 1), (x, y - 1), (x, y + 1)]
    else:
        return [(x, y - 1), (x, y + 1), (x + 1, y - 1), (x + 1, y + 1)]


def cornersOf(x, y):
    return [(x - 1, y), (x + 1, y), (x, y - 2), (x, y + 2)]


def updatePathFieldNode(cx, cy, pending, costField):
    baseValue = pathField[cx][cy].value
    for x, y in sidesOf(cx, cy):
        if inField(x, y):
            newValue = baseValue - sideStepCost - costField[x][y]
            if newValue > pathField[x][y].value:
                pathField[x][y].value = newValue
                pathField[x][y].prev = (cx, cy)
                pathField[x][y].cost = sideStepCost
                pending.append((x, y))
    for x, y in cornersOf(cx, cy):
        if inField(x, y):
            newValue = baseValue - cornerStepCost - costField[x][y]
            if newValue > pathField[x][y].value:
                pathField[x][y].value = newValue
                pathField[x][y].prev = (cx, cy)
                pathField[x][y].cost = cornerStepCost
                pending.append((x, y))


def generatePathField(initx, inity, initValue, costField):
    clearPathField()
    pending = deque()
    if inField(initx, inity):
        pathField[initx][inity].value = initValue
        pending.append((initx, inity))
    while len(pending) != 0:
        (x, y) = pending.popleft()
        updatePathFieldNode(x, y, pending, costField)


def buildPathTo(x, y, cost):
    path = []
    current = (x, y)
    while current is not None:
        path.insert(0, [current, cost])
        cx, cy = current
        current = pathField[cx][cy].prev
    # print(path)
    return path


def create_move_map(posX, posY, points, map):
    costField = refresh_cost_list()
    for tile in map.objects_list:
        costField[tile.column_index][tile.row_index] = float('inf')
    for unit in config.current_player.map_units:  # Запретить движение на места других юнитов
        costField[unit.coords[0]][unit.coords[1]] = float('inf')
    generatePathField(posX, posY, points, costField)
    moves_list = []
    for x in range(fwidth):
        for y in range(fheight):
            if pathField[x][y].value != 0:
                moves_list.append(buildPathTo(x, y, pathField[x][y].cost))
    return moves_list


def refresh_cost_list():
    return [[0 for _ in range(fheight)] for _ in range(fwidth)]
```